# Вычисления после запроса к таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Делаю определенный запрос к таблице

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,a,b FROM mytable");
```

Как посчитать сумму всех значений "a", и отдельно сумму всех значений "b" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT sum(a), sum(b) FROM mytable");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $result['sum(a)'],' ',$result['sum(b)'];
```

Либо

```
$suma = 0;
$sumb = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $suma += $row['a'];
    $sumb += $row['a'];
}
```